# Input parameters of CITemperatureAndTint (CIFilter)

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, core-image

I fail to understand the input parameters of the CIFilter named CITemperatureAndTint. The documentation says it has two input parameters which are both a 2D CIVector.

I played with this filter a lot - via actual code, via Core Image Fun House (example project from Apple - "FunHouse") and via iPhoto.

My intuition says that this filter should have two scalar input parameters: One for the temperature and one for the tint. If you look at the UI of iPhoto you see this:

Screenshot of iPhotos Temperature and Tint UI:

[image: Screenshot of iPhotos Temperature and Tint UI]

As expected: One slider for the temperature and one for the hue. **How did apple "bind" the value of each slider to a 2D-Vector?** akaru asked this question already but got no answer: [What's up with CITemperatureAndTint having vector inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999571/whats-up-with-citemperatureandtint-having-vector-inputs)

Comment: Could you please upload the image using Ctrl+G?

Comment: I have not enough reputation to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have opened a technical support incident at Apple and asked them the same question. Here is the answer from the Apple engineer:

> CITemperatureAndTint has three input parameters: Image, Neutral and
>   TargetNeutral. Neutral and TargetNeutral are of 2D CIVector type, and
>   in both of them, note that the first dimension refers to Temperature
>   and the second dimension refers to Tint. What the CITemperatureAndTint
>   filter basically does is computing a matrix that adapts RGB values
>   from the source white point defined by Neutral (srcTemperature,
>   srcTint) to the target white point defined by TargetNeutral
>   (dstTemperature, dstTint), and then applying this matrix on the input
>   image (using the CIColorMatrix filter). If Neutral and TargetNeutral
>   are of the same values, then the image will not change after applying
>   this filter. I don't know the implementation details about iPhoto, but
>   I think the two slide bars give the Temperature and Tint changes (i.e.
>   differences between source and target Temperature and Tint values
>   already) that you want to add to the source image.

Now I have to get my head around this answer but it seems to be a very good response from Apple.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out what values the slider changes and what the minimum and maximum of the slider should be (for both temperature and tint?). i.e., when the user slides the slider for temperature, what value is being adjusted? and what are the limits on the slider?

Comment: Following answer in another thread has min max values in comment.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202453/152853

Comment: Temperature is measured in Kelvin, and represents the "temperature" of the light source as modeled by a blackbody emitter. The filter will allow it to range from 2000 to positive infinity, but 10000 is a more useful upper bound. Tint is unitless and ranges from about -100 (very green) to +100 (very magenta). Values outside this range are permitted, but they lead to very heavy distortion.

Answer (score 1):

They should be 2D vectors containing the color temperature. The default of (6500, 0) will leave the color unchanged, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html). You can see what values for color temperature give you which colors in [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature). I'm not sure what the 2nd element of the vector is for.