# Drawing an image with a color tint in MonoTouch

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.ios

What do I need to read up on to tint the image I draw with a predefined color. Alternatively just adjust the alpha value? I've played around with BlendMode but I basically don't know what I'm doing. :)

Simplyfied code below

```
_backgroundImage = UIImage.FromFile ("whiteblock.png"); 

var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

// What do I do here to tint or adjust alpha of the image       
ctx.DrawImage (rect, _backgroundImage.CGImage);
```

Thanks

AnkMannen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend starting with the [Core Image Filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) reference docs (see also **[CIFilter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**).
(Note that depending on the version of the OS, not all filters may be available.)

You probably want to focus on the filters in the CICategoryColorAdjustment category.
In particular, the **CITemperatureAndTint** filter can adjust the tint of the image, as you ask.  But, it is not straightforward to use.* There are other questions on StackOverflow describing it, like this one: [Input parameters of CITemperatureAndTint (CIFilter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629411/input-parameters-of-citemperatureandtint-cifilter)

Finally check out the MonoTouch docs for a code example with [CITemperatureAndTint](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=C:MonoTouch.CoreImage.CITemperatureAndTint). (I believe the image attached to the examples given there are wrong, as they show a scaled image, not a tinted image.)

*It takes two parameters, each a 2D CIVector. I believe the first component of the vector is temperature and should be in the ballpark of (1k ... 30k). I believe the second component is wavelength, so in the ballpark of (380 ... 700). If someone knows better, correct me.