# How to apply Cool and warm tone CIFilter on image in iOS?

Tags: swift, core-image, cifilter, imagefilter

I want the same filter as shown in the video, What I have used is below code but I am not able to get the exact filter. I will appreciate if somebody helps me.

```
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CITemperatureAndTint")!
let originalImage = self.imgView.image    // replace yourimage with the name of your image
let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: originalImage!)!
self.filter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let warmX = (sender.value) + 6500
let warmy = (5 + sender.value) + 380

self.filter.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(warmX), y: 0), forKey: "inputNeutral")
self.filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 6500, y: 0), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
print("warm:\(warmX,warmy)")
```

[Filter Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q07UoNwf-EH-jOgumRFo5FmTygyIevz-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The order in your code is a bit confusing... I assume `self.filter` is also a `CITemperatureAndTint` filter? What's `var filter` for? What's the range of your slider?

Comment: Please check I have updated the code, And the `range` is `min = -700` and
`max = 700`

Comment: Are you getting _any_ results? What doesn't match up?

Comment: My code is working fine, the issue is while long-press on the slider it continues to increase my filter layer on the image, so I want to apply my filter when I scroll the slider, not on long-press on the slide or continue move slider at the min and max value.

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact filter you could check out [color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) to see which color temperature results in which color. You can also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999571/whats-up-with-citemperatureandtint-having-vector-inputs) where the usage of the vectors were explained.

Then you should structure your code.

```
let originalImage = self.imgView.image    // replace yourimage with the name of your image
let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: originalImage!)!


var filter = CIFilter(name: "CITemperatureAndTint")!
filter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let warmX = (sender.value) + 6500
let warmy = (5 + sender.value) + 380 // Was never used

filter.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(warmX), y: 0), forKey: "inputNeutral")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 6500, y: 0), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
print("warm:\(warmX,warmy)")
```

Then you should play around with your slider. Basically a cold filter is applied by using these values:

```
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 16000, y: 1000), forKey: "inputNeutral")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 500), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
```

And a warm filter is achieved by using these values:

```
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 6500, y: 500), forKey: "inputNeutral")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 630), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
```

[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177053/how-to-apply-cool-and-warm-tone-cifilter-in-ios)

Comment: My code is working fine, the issue is while long-press on the slider it continues to increase my filter layer on the image, so I want to apply my filter when I scroll the slider, not on long-press on the slide or continue move slider at the min and max value.

Comment: So the problem is your slider ? I think you should also provide your slider coding.

Comment: the slider `value 0, Min= -700 and Max = 700`
I have written my code in this method.
 `@objc func onSliderValChanged(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {`

Comment: Ah! This is probably the issue: `let originalImage = self.imgView.image`. You are using the _already filtered_ image and apply the filter again to it. You need to store the original somewhere else and use it as base.